# How to SELECT FROM a given level of a JSON column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, select, jsonpath, mysql-json

I got a JSON column (`users.roles`) with a structure like

```
{
    "tenant-foo":
    [
        "role-aaa",
        "role-bbb"
    ],
    "tenant-bar":
    [
        "role-bbb",
        "role-ccc"
    ],
    "tenant-buz":
    [
        "role-aaa",
        "role-ccc"
    ],
    ...
    "tenant-...": {
        "role-...",
        ...
    }

}
```

(The semantic behind it: User roles in a multy-tenant system, where a user can be assigned to multiple companies / tenants and get differet roles in every one of them.)

Now I need only the rows, where one of the `roles` is e.g. `role-aaa`.

Is it possible / How to get the rows with a given value (here: `role-aaa`) on the given level (here: the second one) only with `SELECT` and `JSON_*` functions in MySQL?

Comment: The moment you need to dig into the JSON in a column it might be time to think about [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) that column.

Comment: Provide data sample and desired output according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Good point. In this case, the data structure is not in my hand, but is given and to be handled as it is. ) But in general you are definitely right.

Comment: What have you tried? How is what you've tried not working?